# Load image src from from label

Tags: forms, cookies, label

i've this webpage http://inogroup.it/edopera/dashboard_configurator_x.htm

Is it possible to load the source of image from a cookie / form label?

For example,

source of image from value/name of form label 1 :)

Thank you very much